# How to expose elasticsearch setup using eck externally

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, haproxy

Hi i would like to expose my elasticsearch cluster in kubernetes created using ECK (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html)  so it can be accessed externally.

I have a requriement to setup `Functionbeat` to ship aws lambda cloudwatch logs to elastcsearch.
Please see `Step 2: Connect to the Elastic Stack`  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-installation-configuration.html

**Attempt**:

I have an elastic load balancer that has haproxy running on it which i use to expose other k8 services externally such as frontends. Ive attempted to modify this to also allow me to expose elasticsearch.

**haproxy**

```
frontend elasticsearch
  bind *:9200
  acl host_data_elasticsearch hdr(host) -i elasticsearch.acme.com
  use_backend elasticsearchApp if host_data_elasticsearch

backend elasticsearchApp
  server data-es data-es-es-http:9200 check rise 1 ssl verify none
```

Im attempting to see if i can connect using the following curl command:

`curl -u "elastic:$ELASTIC_PASSWORD" -k "https://elasticsearch.acme.com:9200"`

However i get the following error:

> curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

In the browser if i navigate to the url i get

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
> **elasticsearch.acme.com**  sent an invalid response.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Does it work when you try to "curl" it using HTTP instead of HTTPS? Usually this error indicates that the site you are trying to reach is not secure.

Comment: you added `ssl` to the server line which instructs haproxy to perform a ssl offload and you didn't add the ssl stuff in the frontend. it seems you should either remove the ssl+verify from the server, add ssl to the front or query a plain http request.

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer as community wiki based on @Joao Morais comment:

> you added ssl to the server line which instructs haproxy to perform a ssl offload and you didn't add the ssl stuff in the frontend. it seems you should either remove the ssl+verify from the server, add ssl to the front or query a plain http request.

Additional information:

`curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number` indicates that you are trying to reach website that is not secure.

To access it you should replace `https:` with `http:` in your `curl` command so it will look like this:

```
curl -u "elastic:$ELASTIC_PASSWORD" -k "http://elasticsearch.acme.com:9200"
```